# JLabel does not show up after changing imageIcon

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

[image]
this is how my GUI looks like. When I click the attack button it should look like this

[image]

the 2 jlabels below(the 2 blue circles) will be replaced. but in my code it only looks like this.. [image]

```
private static String[] imageList = {"/com.baylon.img/rock.png","/com.baylon.img/paper.png","/com.baylon.img/scissors.png"};

private void btnAttackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   int compChoice = (int)(Math.random()*3);
   int playerChoice =  getVal((String)cboxPlayerChoice.getSelectedItem());
   int numRounds = Integer.parseInt(txtNumRounds.getText());
    ImageIcon rock = new ImageIcon(imageList[0]);
     ImageIcon paper = new ImageIcon(imageList[1]);
      ImageIcon scissors = new ImageIcon(imageList[2]);


   if(playerChoice == 0 ){
       lblImgPlayer.setIcon(rock);
       lblImgPlayer.setVisible(true);
      if(compChoice == 1){
          lblImgComp.setIcon(paper); //player loses
          lblImgComp.setVisible(true);
       }else if(compChoice == 2){
            lblImgComp.setIcon(scissors); 
             lblImgComp.setVisible(true);//player wins
       }else if(compChoice == 0){
            lblImgComp.setIcon(rock);
             lblImgComp.setVisible(true);//draw
       }
   }

   if(playerChoice == 1){
        lblImgPlayer.setIcon(paper);
       if(compChoice == 0){
            lblImgComp.setIcon(rock);//player wins
       }else if(compChoice == 1){
            lblImgComp.setIcon(paper);//draw
       }else if(compChoice == 2){
            lblImgComp.setIcon(scissors);//player loses
       }
   }

    if(playerChoice == 2){
        lblImgPlayer.setIcon(scissors);
       if(compChoice == 0){
           lblImgComp.setIcon(rock);//player loses
       }else if(compChoice == 1){
           lblImgComp.setIcon(paper);//player wins
       }else if(compChoice == 2){
           lblImgComp.setIcon(scissors);//draw
       }
   }



}
```

i tried setting the jlabels' visibility to true but it still doesnt work. Any idea on how to do this? We'll be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve].

Comment: `lblImgComp.setIcon(rock);`Have you checked whether `rock` is actually not null?

Comment: what layout manager are you using? if you attach a click event to the jlabel, for possibly a jmessagepanel (equivalent of alert box, if I recall correctly), does it pop up? Is the image actually linked correctly? You need to provide more details please.

Comment: @FredK i've edited my question. I added in my code part how I added an imagelist and assigned it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Attempts to repaint the panel that contains these components in action attack button

```
jpanel.repaint();
```